# What format do I use for a string variable in a query

Tags: excel, vba

I am performing a web query and want to filter a column by a cell reference.

```
ThisWeek = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value

LastWeek = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("M1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="1245", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = 
    Json.Document(Web.Contents(""" & finalstr & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & 
    Chr(10) & "     each ([Column1.report_begin_date] = " < " & ThisWeek & " > " 
    or [Column1.report_begin_date] = " < " & Last Week & " > ")"    
    #""Filtered Rows"""
```

ThisWeek and LastWeek are both strings that change each day and I want the query to filter out by these dates. VBA doesn't recognize the way Im formatting my variable names and doesn't recognize them as an editable variable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is add quotation marks for your date string variable, correct?

You can achieve that by using: *""""* (4 times quotation marks)
Which will create a simple ***"***

So if you add it to both sides of your string variable, you will get what you need, as follows:

```
[...] " < " & """" & ThisWeek & """" & [...]
```

Hope this helps